# UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

```
let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboardTap))
func hideKeyboardTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view.isUserinteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)
```

Xcode reports "swift compiler error: Expected declaration" when I run the above code.
There must be mistake in this line `hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1`but I could not find out. Would you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: In which method you have put this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try same this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       
        let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideKeyboardTap(_:))
       hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
       self.view.isUserinteractionEnabled = true
       self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)
    }

func hideKeyboardTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Right, I put this code in a wrong place. Stupid me !

Comment: @Wilson your function have input param , note: self.hideKeyboardTap(_:)

Answer (score 2):

Write like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func doubleTapped() {
// do something cool here
}
```

Comment: Right, I put this code in a wrong place. Stupid me !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboardTap:"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!